# How can I ajax data from an HTML form with checkboxes into a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-sheets

I'm trying to pull data from an HTML form into a Google Sheet by using AJAX. I've gotten it to work fine with all types of inputs EXCEPT checkboxes. I've gotten it to return the first value checked, but not all values checked.

Relevant parts of the markup and script below. Entry numbers and form URL are correct.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cb1" value="Scholarship1">Scholarship 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb1" value="Scholarship2">Scholarship 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb1" value="Scholarship3">Scholarship 3

<script type="text/javascript">
        function postToGoogle() {


           var formData = {
                "entry.1226541462": $('.cb1').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1SqNCVpcZJ4N3huh8SrkU_uWuHFEBb2nCQXgUz3stI/formResponse",
                data: formData,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                statusCode: {
                    0: function() {
                        window.location.replace("thanks.html");
                    },
                    200: function() {
                        window.location.replace("thanks.html");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.form').submit(function() {
                postToGoogle();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to submit to exactly? POST data into a spreadsheet at a given column/row?

Also how would you send the data if you have multiple values? comma-delimited, javascript array, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd get all the checked values into an array:

```
var yourArray = [];

//I think this selector is correct, but veri
$("input:checkbox.cb1:checked").each(function(){
    yourArray.push($(this).val());
});

//If comma-delimited string.
var valueToSend = yourArray.join();
```

I do not fully know the API, so I'm assuming google sheets accepts a comma-delimited array.

Comment: And then just change the formData variable to:

    var formData = {
                "entry.1226541462": valueToSend
            };

in order to send the array to Google?

Comment: I'm making an assumption here. Check their API documentation, as I can't tell if you intend to post to Sheets or Forms.